# CodeIgniter passing a variable to a Modal then to a View

Tags: forms, codeigniter, url, variables

I have a list of cities in my database. There is an edit button that brings up a modal with a form where they can change the name of the city and submit. I'm having a hard time getting the city_id to pass from the edit button through the modal and to the controller. I get a "message undefined variable for the city_id on the line that tries to put the city_id in the form open code.

Adding a modal into the mix has made this confusing to me.

View Code

```
<a href="#" class="btn edit-modal" data-id="<?php echo $c['city_id']; ?>"  data-name="<?php echo  $c['city_name']; ?>">Edit</a>

<!-- Modal for Edit -->
<div class="modal hide" id="editCityDialog">
<div class="modal-header">
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
    <h3>Edit City</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <?php $this->load->helper('form'); ?>
        <?php echo form_open('/cities/edit_city/'. $city_id); ?>
        <label class="control-label" for="name">City</label>
        <input type="text" name="city_name" id="city_name" value=""/><br />
        <input type="submit" class="btn-small btn-primary" value="Edit City" />
        <button class="btn-small" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div>
```

```
<!-- jQuery for Modal -->
<script>
  // scripts for modal windows
$(document).on("click", ".edit-modal", function () {
    var city_name = $(this).data('name');
    var city_id = $(this).data('id');
    $(".modal-body #city_name").val( city_name );
    $('#editCityDialog').modal('show');
});
</script>
```

Controller Code

```
// Edit City
public function edit_city() {
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);

    if ($this->input->city('submit')) {
        $city_name = $this->input->xss_clean($this->input->city('city_name'));
        $this->cities_model->edit_city($city_id, $city_name);
    }
}
```

Model Code

```
// Edit City
public function edit_city($city_id, $city_name) {
    $data = array(
        'city_name' => $city_name
    );
    $this->db->where('city_id', $city_id);
    $this->db->update('cities', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `city_id` you already have and set the action with that:

```
$(document).on("click", ".edit-modal", function () {
    var city_name = $(this).data('name');
    var city_id = $(this).data('id');
    $(".modal-body #city_name").val( city_name );
    //set the forms action to include the city_id
    $(".modal-body form").attr('action','/cities/edit_city/'+city_id);
    $('#editCityDialog').modal('show');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if echoing `<?php echo $c['city_id']; ?>` works for the edit button, you should do that for the form_open as well like this

```
<?php echo form_open('/cities/edit_city/'. $c['city_id']); ?>
```

I would also recommend that if your `edit_city()` function is only ever called if there is a `segment(3)`, then it is easier to do this:

```
// Edit City
public function edit_city($id) {

    if ($this->input->city('submit')) {
        $city_name = $this->input->xss_clean($this->input->city('city_name'));
        $this->cities_model->edit_city($city_id, $city_name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried that, did not work. The modal is outside the loop so $c['city_id'] won't match the city_id we want to edit.

Comment: You have not posted any loop code so how should i have known that.

Comment: I know it's kind of bloated, but you could always put the modal stuff inside your loop and then `$c['city_id']` would work.